# Nested Objects in Bootstrap.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm making some improvements to a Combobox class I made to go with Bootstrap 4, and I wanted to make the Javascript match what already exists in Bootstrap.

In the process, I found some code that I don't quite understand in `bootstrap.js` while checking out the Modal:

```
var Modal = function () {
    var NAME = 'modal';
    // Other Constants

    var Modal =
    /*#__PURE__*/
    function() {
        function Modal(element, config) {
            this._config = this._getconfig(config);
            // Other Assignments
        }

        var _proto = Modal.prototype;
        // Other Prototype Assignments
    }();
}($);
```

My question is this: Why is `var Modal = function() ...` nested inside itself? What does this nested pattern accomplish? Should I use this pattern in my Combobox?

Answer (score 0):

We use a Babel to compile our plugins in ES5 but our code source is in ES6, so for me this question should be related to Babel questions